# How to call SQL Function with multiple parameters from C# web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-function

I have an MS SQL function that is called with the following syntax:

```
SELECT Field1, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount
FROM GetDecileTable('WHERE ClientID = 7 AND LocationName = ''Default'' ', 10)
```

The first parameter passes a specific `WHERE` clause that is used by the function for one of the internal queries.  When I call this function in the front-end C# page, I need to send parameter values for the individual fields inside of the `WHERE` clause (in this example, both the `ClientID` & `LocationName` fields)

The current C# code looks like this:

```
String SQLText = "SELECT Field1, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM GetDecileTable('WHERE
                  ClientID = @ClientID AND LocationName = @LocationName ',10)";
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLText, SqlConnection);
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 7; // Insert real ClientID
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@LocationName", SqlDbType.NVarChar(20)).Value = "Default";
               // Real code uses Location Name from user input
SqlDataReader reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

When I do this, I get the following code from SQL profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT Field1, COUNT(*) as RecordCount FROM GetDecileTable
(''WHERE ClientID = @ClientID AND LocationName = @LocationName '',10)',
N'@ClientID int,@LocationID nvarchar(20)',
@ClientID=7,@LocationName=N'Default'
```

When this executes, SQL throws an error that it cannot parse past the first mention of `@ClientID` stating that the Scalar Variable `@ClientID` must be defined.  If I modify the code to declare the variables first (see below), then I receive an error at the second mention of `@ClientID` that the variable already exists.

```
exec sp_executesql N'DECLARE @ClientID int; DECLARE @LocationName nvarchar(20); 
SELECT Field1, COUNT(*) as RecordCount FROM GetDecileTable
(''WHERE ClientID = @ClientID AND LocationName = @LocationName '',10)',
N'@ClientID int,@LocationName nvarchar(20)',
@ClientID=7,@LocationName=N'Default'
```

I know that this method of adding parameters and calling SQL code from C# works well when I am selecting data from tables, but I am not sure how to embed parameters inside of the ' quote marks for the embedded `WHERE` clause being passed to the function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was

```
SELECT Field1, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM GetDecileTable('WHERE
ClientID = @ClientID AND LocationName = @LocationName ',10)
```

should

```
SELECT Field1, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM GetDecileTable('WHERE
ClientID = ' + @ClientID + ' AND LocationName = ' + @LocationName,10)
```

your variables are used inside string where they are considered just as part of it.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fit the bill in this situation.  The problem comes because of the embedded quotes in the sub-WHERE clause.